# Avoid null terminating string in assembly

Tags: string, assembly, hex, nasm, shellcode

I am working on an assignment and I have this assembly code:

```
    PUSH    EDX                           
    PUSH    0x7461
    PUSH    0x6374
    PUSH    0x656e
```

where the hex was "6e6574636174"

and it compiles with nasm to:

```
       52                          PUSH    EDX                           
       6861740000                  PUSH    0x7461
       6874630000                  PUSH    0x6374
       686E650000                  PUSH    0x656e
```

how can I write the assembly in such a way that there are no zeros in the output to the left? I want to get get rid of the null terminating strings.

This is the first assembly program I have ever written, complete noob...

Thank you!

Comment: These are not strings. They're 32 bit integers where the higher 16 bits are 0..

Comment: You forgot that that you are in 32 bit mode. You should pack 4 characters (8 hex digits) into each `push`. Since you have 6 chars, you will have 2 unused, just put something other than zeroes in there :)

Comment: @interjay I am trying to get the stack to have the ascii characters "netcat"

Comment: @Jester could you show me an example of what you mean please?

Comment: Pad it out to 8 bytes either at the front or at the end as appropriate. E.g. `push 'tcat'; push '##ne'` That's assuming you want to use `push`.

Comment: @Jester yes i'll use push. so I've packed 8 hex digits into the first push and in the second push I end up with . `6874636174    PUSH    0x74616374` and
   `686E650000                  PUSH    0x656e` so, pad the PUSH 0x656e with a "##" which would be PUSH 0x656e2323 ?

Comment: nasm understands ascii no need to mess with hex. But yeah, that looks correct (but haven't checked the hex :)) Of course if you padded the front, the string begins at `esp+2` in memory so make sure you use that address later.

Comment: ok let me try and I'll report back

Comment: @Jester I can see "##netcat" So thing that satisfies the original question, although Idk how to get rid of the "##"

Comment: As I said, just use `esp+2` as address later.

Comment: yes ok. like MOV esp, 2 PUSH esp ? and if you want to add your answer I can accept =)

Comment: No that wouldn't be very good, that's not adding 2 :) If you want to push the address to the stack too, then you can do something like `lea eax, [esp+2]; push eax` or `push esp; add dword [esp], 2`.

Comment: @Jester this is the whole function in assembly that I'm working with. you can see the two PUSH statements with the "netcat" hex
```
PUSH    EDX                           ; Stack = 0
    PUSH    0x74616374
    PUSH    0x656e2323       ; Stack = "netcat", 0 
    PUSH    ESP
    POP     ECX                           ; ECX = &("netcat")
    PUSH    EDX                           ; Stack = 0, "calc", 0
    PUSH    ECX                           ; Stack = &("netcat"), 0, "netcat", 0
```

Comment: Well then you want `push esp; pop ecx; add ecx, 2`

Comment: `push esp; add dword [esp], 2` gave me more null terminated strings

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200203/discussion-between-ssl-and-jester).